# How to fix MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: wagtailcore_site doesn't exist?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

Presently I am deploying my website to [pythonanywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com) everything is perfect exclude the [front-side](http://transonhoang.pythonanywhere.com/) of my website.

I got `Internal server error` for the front-site then I check out the log file and I noticed this

```
MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'transonhoang$default.wagtailcore_site' doesn't exist")
**NO MATCH**
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
**NO MATCH**
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/transonhoang/.virtualenvs/my-blog/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/transonhoang/.virtualenvs/my-blog/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 90, in __call__
    response = self.process_request(request)
  File "/home/transonhoang/.virtualenvs/my-blog/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtail/core/middleware.py", line 13, in process_request
    request.site = Site.find_for_request(request)
  File "/home/transonhoang/.virtualenvs/my-blog/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtail/core/models.py", line 120, in find_for_request
    return get_site_for_hostname(hostname, port)
  File "/home/transonhoang/.virtualenvs/my-blog/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtail/core/sites.py", line 35, in get_site_for_hostname
    'root_page'
  File "/home/transonhoang/.virtualenvs/my-blog/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 268, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/transonhoang/.virtualenvs/my-blog/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1186, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/home/transonhoang/.virtualenvs/my-blog/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 54, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/home/transonhoang/.virtualenvs/my-blog/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1065, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/transonhoang/.virtualenvs/my-blog/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/transonhoang/.virtualenvs/my-blog/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/transonhoang/.virtualenvs/my-blog/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/transonhoang/.virtualenvs/my-blog/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/transonhoang/.virtualenvs/my-blog/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/transonhoang/.virtualenvs/my-blog/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 71, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/home/transonhoang/.virtualenvs/my-blog/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/home/transonhoang/.virtualenvs/my-blog/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 312, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/home/transonhoang/.virtualenvs/my-blog/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 224, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'transonhoang$default.wagtailcore_site' doesn't exist")
2019-04-24 08:19:06,212: Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/transonhoang/.virtualenvs/my-blog/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/transonhoang/.virtualenvs/my-blog/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 71, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/home/transonhoang/.virtualenvs/my-blog/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/home/transonhoang/.virtualenvs/my-blog/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 312, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/home/transonhoang/.virtualenvs/my-blog/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 224, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
```

What is `MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'transonhoang$default.wagtailcore_site' doesn't exist")` meaning?

My step: https://github.com/texperience/wagtail-pythonanywhere-quickstart

Comment: Did you remember to do the `python manage.py migrate` step?

Comment: Yes I did it without any errors. That why the admin page is still good. But the frontside I got the error. It is weird to me.

Comment: Do the other wagtail tables exist in your database? Is it possible that you ran the migrate before adding wagtail to your settings?